# Locust eats CPU after 2-3 hours running

Tags: locust

I have a simple HTTP server that I was testing. This server interacts with other HTTP servers and Cassandra DB.

Currently I was using 100 users with 1 request/s, so totally 100 tps was on the server. What I noticed with the Docker stats was that the CPU usage became higher and higher and ~ 2-3 hours later the CPU usage reaches the 90% mark, and even more. After that I got a notice from Locust, stating that the measurement may be inconsistent. But the latencies were not increased, so I do not know why this has been happening.

Can you please suggest possible cause(s) of the problem? I think 100 tps should be handled by one vCPU.

Thanks,

AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way for us to know exactly what's wrong without at very least seeing some code, and even then other factors like the environment or data or server you're running it on or against could have additional factors we wouldn't know about.

It's possible you have a problem with your code for your Locust users, such as a memory leak or they're just doing too much for a single worker to handle that many users. For users only doing simple HTTP calls, a single CPU typically can handle upwards of thousands of requests per second. Do anything more than that and you'll start to expect to reduce what a worker can handle. It's also possible you may just need a more powerful CPU (or more RAM or bandwidth) to do what you want it to do at the scale you want.

Do some profiling to see if you can find any inefficiencies in your code. Run smaller tests to see if the same behavior is evident with smaller loads. Run the same load but with additional Locust workers on other CPUs.

It's also just as possible your DB can't handle the load. The increasing CPU usage could be due to how your code is handling waiting on the connection from the DB. Perhaps the DB could sustain, say, 80 users at an acceptable rate but any additional users makes it fall further and further behind and your Locust users are then waiting longer and longer for the requested data.

For more suggestions, check out the Locust FAQ https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/FAQ#increase-my-request-raterps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked the python file and it seems that I found the problem. At least now it is running almost an hour and the cpu load is not increasing.